# Defining hooks inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I would like to create a bunch of filters to pause or play my Video. My implementation is something like as shown below:

```
const Player = () => {
  const playFilters = [useIsPageVisible(), useIsInViewport(videoElement)];
  const player = useInitPlayer();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (player) {
      if (playFilters.every((filter) => filter)) {
        player.play()
      } else {
        player.pause()
      }
    }
  }, [player, playFilters])

return <Player player={player}/>
}
```

I know defining hooks inside an `if` condition is not correct. But how about defining them as above? Could it be done in a better way?

Comment: It's fine, it didn't violate any rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks, it's crucial that  hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That's why one of the **Rules of Hooks** is **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions**.

Storing hook results in an array does not break that rule (or any other rule), there it is is perfectly fine to do that.

See more details [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).